# Can I target and change jquery created pseudo <img> src by css?

Tags: jquery, css

So my problem is there that i don't know how to target classes created with jquery with CSS.Not only that,but i don't know even how to change src and alt values  of it..I will leave similar code to mine down here and if anyone know how to target those elements,or even if is it possible,please give an advice.

Example:`<img src="test1" alt="test2">`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOjzVM there is my codepen,i want to target each of elements first.Than if element is  i want to change src and alt values of it.

Comment: CSS can't change any attribute value, only apply visual style.

Comment: So i guess it will be better to remove jquery script for cloning elements and  copy 14 times my html code and style it with css :?

Comment: @Dako yes. you might change image to show with css by using some cheats but you can never change alt attribute

Comment: @Dako - could you please elaborate more about your end to end goal. what you want after loop of 12? Do you want to assign different image in each box?

Comment: Nope i want to can edit every single element's src and alt values in the loop.

I am making something like table with divs in which there i a pictures with text,so i cloned those elements,because if i need to copy them 12 times code is getting large,like 50+ rows of additional code,thats why i cloned them and want to edit them 1 by one.The code will be smaller than if i copy HTML code x12 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using jQuery. No need for CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   for (var i=0; i<12; i++){
       var src = "";
       var alt = "";          
       if (i == 0) {  
          src = "sourcePathHere";
          alt = "anything";
       }
       else if (i == 1) {
          src = "sourcePathHere2";
          alt = "anything2";  
       }
       //and so on...

       $('body').append('<div class="food-content" ><img src="' + src + '" alt="' + alt + '"></div>');
   }
});
```

Comment: I am asking to how(if there is a way) to target each element and edit them one my one with different src's and alt's. :P

Comment: then the answer above should work. I will update the answer to be more specific.

Comment: please note however, that as this shortens the html code.. it uses more jQuery code :)

Comment: yap mate its cool and it completely answers my question.Can i ask 1 more question,because I'am new.Which code makes browser slower Jquery or HTML.
Lets say we have problem like mine my HTML is 4 elements in one another and i need copy of them.Clone method and edit each element one by one,or copy 12 times HTMl code and edit it right in there?
Sorry i know it is out of the theme,but if you can please answer.

Comment: Generally there wouldn't be much difference on normal cases. Here is a similar question to what you are asking

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840776/performance-difference-between-static-html-rendering-and-dynamic-dom-element-ren